# PHP - SSAS - MSOLAP ISAPI Extension msmdpump.dll Access denied

Tags: php, iis, ssas, olap, olap-cube

I'm try to build a PHP application using the phpOLAPi library "https://github.com/kabachello/phpOLAPi" to connect over the SSAS server to make a pivote table.

by googling, i followed this steps : [From Microsoft web site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/configure-http-access-to-analysis-services-on-iis-8-0?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=asallproducts-allversions&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-ver15) to configure the webservice application to connecte to the SSAS server.

i'm stuck now with this error :

> The following error occurred while writing to the file 'MSOLAP ISAPI Extension: \? \ C: \ inetpub \ wwwroot \ SSAS \ ​​msmdpump.dll': Access denied

the authentication here is **Anonymos** cause i set my own login/password through it ( my accout has access directly to SSAS via SSMS )

iv even remove all configuration and start from the begining, but getting the same error.

**NOTE : IIS and SSAS are separated, there are not in the same server !**

thanks

**UPDATE 1**

i resolved this issue for the Access denied error by adding login/password in the PoolApplication that i created and testing if has the windows right as Admin, now i have a new issue :
when i start the IIS for the first time it give me the result, in the next refresh it say there is an internal error, but when I restared the IIS and refresh the page for the first time, it grappe the data from SSAS the second page refresh give the error.

Any idea ?

**Update 2 :**

Here is the error message it's in frensh :
[image]

Comment: Can you post the internal error message in the next refresh? and what is error with the second page refresh.

Comment: i updated the question by adding the error message in the second refresh, i searched for the error code, but it send me to a Microsoft Update to make in SSAS , but this one dossn't accept the giving update from Microsoft !